# Spring Boot swallowing Access-Control-Request-Headers on OPTIONS preflight

Tags: spring, http-headers, spring-boot, cors, preflight

I have a Spring Boot REST application that has a very simple CORS filter on it. What I want to do is dynamically respond to the values in the Access-Control-Request-Headers header, rather than provide a specific list. The common wisdom seems to be the explicitly set the values returned in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", however we will be white-listing a set of origins and want to allow any headers they send. I cannot find a way to parrot back the value of Access-Control-Allow-Headers in Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Here's the code

```
   @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS"); // will need to enable other methods when/as implemented
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

With this request & response from Chrome (when we were hard-coding the value of Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

```
Remote Address:10.199.240.16:443
Request URL:https://myapp.com/gradebooks/5566669e-e4b0-d05e-0150-98d7ffffffff/assignments/3ad7f1e7-679b-4d8b-856e-d2e3589eaad6
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
    view source
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Max-Age → 3600
    Content-Type → application/hal+json; charset=UTF-8
    Date → Tue, 21 Jul 2015 20:42:29 GMT
    Server → Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
    Transfer-Encoding → chunked
    X-Application-Context → application

Request Headers
    view source
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
    Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:gbservices-api.dev-prsn.com
    Origin:http://localhost:3000
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
```

This is the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://myapp.com/gradebooks/5566669e-e4b0-d05e-0150-98d7ffffffff/assignments/3ad7f1e7-679b-4d8b-856e-d2e3589eaad6.
>   Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

What I've found debugging into the filter is that the Access-Control-Request-Headers, and only that header, is missing by the time it gets to the filter. Misspell the header and it arrives, so it seems that something is intercepting the header and discarding it before it gets to my filter...